# MySQL - EER Diagram - A group must have certain type of member

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database, one part of my database is that,
there are different Groups and there are Members in them.
There are some requirements, a group MUST have a member wearing red cloth, and a member wearing yellow and a member wearing blue. It can have members wearing other colour but is optional for the group to exist.

I'm not sure how can I do it in an elegant way.
This is my current concept:

[image: MY EER]

Comment: Your current solution seems to imply that "a group has one or more members", "each member is wearing red", "each member is wearing blue", "each member is wearing yellow", and "each member is zero or more members wearing anything". I don't think that works the way you think it does.

Comment: In general, always do your data modeling on conceptual and logical levels before even opening a DB tool ;)

Comment: For anything other than the specific task of assessing group validity, this design is very poor. Instead, I think I would handle this kind of logic at the application level. So conceptually, *any* combination of users can instigate a 'group', but the validity of that group will be assessed within the query, rather than the DB design.

Comment: @Strawberry, sort of agree, sort of disagree... I do think it's good practice to include business logic in your data model, because that way it's instantly visible for anyone looking at the model. However, what parts of the logic in the data model are implemented in the DB and what parts are implemented at application level is a different discussion. It's a crucial and often neglected issue of data model vs. actual DB implementation (or logical vs. physical modelling, if you wish).

Comment: @user333014, I see that you are new at Stack Overflow, so a friendly reminder: if an answer is useful to you, please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Your current concept is wrong. It seems to imply that "a group has one or more members", "each member is wearing red", "each member is wearing blue", "each member is wearing yellow", and "each member is zero or more members wearing anything".

A more correct solution would be the following (please excuse my short-hand notation, it's just quickly mashed up in Visio):

[image]

**Group** is now connected directly to the *sub-types* of **Member**. Each member is *either* a member wearing red, a member wearing blue, a member wearing yellow, or a member wearing something else. The common attributes are in the **Member** table.

As you can see, it's still not a very elegant as a DB solution. As Strawberry noted in the comments of OP, this kind of logic should probably be implemented at the application layer rather than in DB. In that case you could have a simple two-table solution with **Group** and **Member**, an attribute for Colour in **Member**, and somewhere in your application a rule that states that a group is only valid if it has these certain members.